# Porque este traductor echo con arrays no me funciona?

Tags: javascript, array, string

Saludos: Estoy tratando de hacer un traductor sin conexión en javascript utilizando dos arrays y no sé en qué parte del código he perdido que no se ejecuta el programa ,¿ alguien podría ayudarme ?.Cuándo trato de obtener los valores del html para procesarlo en el script el programa no se ejecuta no entiendo qué es lo que pasa es que no el código no se ejecuta.

```html
**<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form action="">
            <select name="formulario" id="lenguaje">
        <option value="1">Español-Ingles</option>
        <option value="3">Ingles-Español</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Palabra-Ord " id="palabra">
            <input type="submit" value="Traducir" onClick="traducirpalabra()">
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
        function traducirpalabra() {
            var frutas = ['manzana', 'naranja']
            var fruits = ['apple', 'orange']
            var palabra = document.getElementById("palabra").value
            var tipo = document.getElementById("lenguaje").value
            var encontro = false
            if (tipo == 1) {
                for (i = 0; i < frutas.length; i++) {
                    if (palabra == frutas[i]) {
                        encontro = true
                        alert('En ingles es' + ' ' + fruits[i])
                        break;
                    }
                    if (encontro != true) {
                        alert('No conozco esa palabra')
                    } else {
                        for (i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
                            if (palabra == fruits[i]) {
                                encontro = true
                                alert('En Español es' + ' ' + frutas[i])
                                break;
                            }
                            if (encontro != true) {
                                alert('No conozco esa palabra')
                            }
                        }
                    }
    </script>
</body>**

</html>
```

Comment: A veces simplemente me sorprenden los errores que se plantean. ¿Acaso no usan un Editor de código cuando programan? ¿Programan en bloc de notas? Los editores de código te resaltan la sintaxis por defecto sin instalar nada. Fue pegarlo en vscode y notar que [te faltan 3 llaves](https://ibb.co/zm4cqwK) `}` por cerrar, y es que salen en rojo como que gritándote ayuda. Además que el mensaje en la consola te lo dice.

Comment: Y el evento change para tomar los values?

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez más respeto que le estás hablando a la iglesia jajajaja

Comment: Me hacen reír...De cierto soy Pastor y agradezco mucho vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Pero en visual studio code no me sale cuando una me falta una llave. Instale un par de extensiones a ver.

Comment: Pero estimados, si con tanta exactitud diste con el problema, porque no lo solucionaste y enviaste el ejemplo.¿ Es muy difícil ?...

Comment: Los errores tipográficos son causa de cierre de las preguntas. No son ese tipo de preguntas los que resolvemos acá. Agrega 3 llaves de cierre antes de la etiqueta de cierre del script y te "funcionará". Y digo "funcionará" porque más o menos funciona de español a inglés pero con varios errores de lógica, pero para ayudarte en eso, conviene que investigues y luego, si no das con el error, reformules tu pregunta y seas específico con lo que quieres. Estamos para ayudar, pero luego de un proceso de investigación y con código que al menos corra sin  errores tipográficos.

Comment: Gracias...Es bueno la comunión entre hermanos no solo en la iglesia en esto de la presentación también. Antes me ponía días tratando de descubrir porque algo faltaba, No me había dado cuenta que existían personas con más conocimiento que yo dispuesto a ayudar en comunidades como estás . Ustedes tienen principios cristianos. Ayudan sin interés. Gracias Me siento feliz por estar en esta comunidad y conocerlos.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a la comunidad! Siento si a veces somos "un poco bruscos" pero es que hay normas importantes para que el sitio funcione de manera correcta. Un buen inicio para conocer cómo funcionamos es leer [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), realizar el [Recorrido de Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que ganes tu primera medalla y leer [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Buena suerte en tu aprendizaje, y ¡no te rindas!